# Import function from another file that itself imports unavailable modules?

Tags: python

I wrote some functions in `a.py`. I run `a.py` with my *generic* python binary. Inside `a.py`, I have

```
import some_module

def simple_function():
    ...

def complex_function():
    some_module.some_func()
```

Now, I want to import `simple_function()` into `b.py`, which has to be run with another python (a software-bundled installation), and this python doesn't have `some_module` installed.

When I run `b.py` (which contains line `from a import simple_function`) with the software-bundled python, I received this error, as expected.

```
ImportError: No module named 'some_module'
```

Is there a way around it? As you see, `simple_function()` does not need `some_module`.

---

One solution I can think of is to put the import statement inside `complex_function`.

```
def simple_function():
    ...

def complex_function():
    import some_module
    some_module.some_func()
```

But I'm sure linters and format checkers will complain about it. Better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to split the complex function into a separate module on its own.

When you import a function within a module, you are importing the entire module.

Other solution is to install `some_module` in the other python installation...

Comment: Thanks. I will go with the first solution. Some software-bundled python is not dev version and has no `Python.h` -- really hard to install modules...

Comment: I strongly recommend using miniconda for creating python environments. https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html?highlight=mini